# Using a Bluetooth or USB remote to advance Keynote slides?

Tags: ipad, remote-control, keynote

What would it take technically for the iPad to be able to allow Keynote slides to be advanced by a remote (like this -  http://www.targus.com/us/productdetail.aspx?regionId=7&sku=AMP18US)?

Or how about via Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

The 2Screens iPad app works with their iPhone remote app for Keynote, PowerPoint, and PDFs through wifi. Apple's Keynote Remote app on an iPhone also offers remote control through wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I’VE GOTTEN A REMOTE TO WORK WITH KEYNOTE ON IPAD

I’m like everyone else wanting a remote to advance slides. Today I got my Magic Trackpad to work with my iPad advancing slides in Keynote though BLUETOOTH. It works perfectly.

Let me go through steps.
1. Jailbroken Ipad (sorry only way around it)
2. Install Bt Stack Mouse – Cydia
3. Ran Bt Stack Mouse
4. Put Track Pad in discovery mode (took several attempts)
5. Once connected – it works like trackpad is supposed to. The pointer works as well.

To use it around the room — press the round rubber buttons on bottom of track pad.

Currently going HDMI out – working perfectly.

Cannot backup — but it advances perfectly from across the room.

OTHER NOTE: Keynote Remote App — with BT Stack Mouse it does recognize “home iphone” but won’t advance to input passcode. Maybe soon that one will work.

Enjoy your presentations with BlueTooth Remote for Keynote Ipad.

Answer (score 1):

Just got WeBE++ to control iPad keynote presentation from iPhone.

Steps: jailbreak iPad - sorry only way around it
Download and install BTstack Mouse - Cydia
Download and install WeBe++ - Cydia
Run BTstack mouse
Run WeBe++

BTstack mouse will recognize WeBe++ as 'name iphone'
Connect - 
Run keynote and load presentation - put presentation in play mode
Click iPhone screen once to advance slides.

Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no RF or Bluetooth (or WiFi) remotes that work with Keynote for iPad at this time. Even the Apple Wireless Keyboard can't do it. I'm expecting the capability to be added in a future release, but there's no telling when that will be.